# NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate destinationURL

Tags: ios, ios6, nsurlconnection, nsdata, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am currently developing an iPad iOS 6 Application which uses async downloads.
To receive progress information i used the delegate `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate`.
The download and the progress received by

```
– connection:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:
```

works just fine.

However once the download is finished, i do not know how to extract the data out of the `NSURL` `destinationURL` provided by the delegatemethod

```
– connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:
```

The destinationURL received in String looks like 
"`/private/var/mobile/Applications/7CB3B194-9E79-4F0B-ACFD-7B87AA8C7BAF/tmp/filename.mp4`"

Then i try to extract the data from the given NSURL:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:destinationURL];
```

The data however is empty...

```
NSLog(@"data Size: %@", data.length);     //prints out 0
```

Has someone the same issue by using `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate`? Any ideas how to solve?

---

Edit: I tried to copy the file first, and then use `[NSData initWithContentsOFFile]` as suggested, but the data size is still 0.

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:destinationURL.path toPath:DEST_PATH error:nil];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DEST_PATH];

NSLog(@"data Size: %i", data.length); //still returns 0..
}
```

---

Edit2:
I can extract the `NSData` when using `sendAsynchronousRequest` method of `NSURLConnection`. However like this, i am not able to determine the progress of the download...

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
if (data){
NSLog(@"Size of the data: %i Bytes(s)", data.length); //works fine
[data writeToFile:DEST_PATH atomically:YES];
//From this point i can use the file at DEST_PATH

NSLog(@"Succeeded!");
}
else if (error)
NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

Comment: what if you copy the file to your content path and try to open it there?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582849/nsurlconnectiondownloaddelegate-expectedtotalbytes-zero-in-ios-6

Comment: Have you looked at the answer from the previous comment?

Comment: yes, but the delegateMethod connection:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes: works fine, and i can show the progress of the download by using a progressbar. So i do not think the problem is in the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the file exists.
I have the same problem and I have to use NSURLConnectionDataDelegate and save the data manually and that's why:
There is an error with NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate related with some file extensions.

Also you could see answers to the same question here:
[NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate file issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754470/nsurlconnectiondownloaddelegate-file-issue)

Comment: Yes there is probably an issue with NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate. I replaced the delegate with NSConnectionDataDelegate, now i am able to download a file async and still displaying the progress of the download.

Answer (score 0):

> /private/var/mobile/Applications/7CB3B194-9E79-4F0B-ACFD-7B87AA8C7BAF/tmp/filename.mp4

is a path, not a URL. Try initWithContentsOfFile: instead.